# when I just import different livery, I have seeing same errors

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, puppeteer

I tried **webdriverio**, **puppeteer**, **playwright, bowser**

and I could see same results with problems using React

I just did

`$ yarn add webdriverio (or other)`

and next

`import { remote } from 'webdriverio';`or `const playwright = require('playwright');`

I did only that...

then I did `$ yarn start`

next is same or close

[image]

I saw this long err log..

it is same that log text means

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os'`

all log are ***'can't resolve 'something'.*** (something : os, fs, http, https, tty .....)

**I tried webpack config for fallback**. the log recommended

but however I added new fallback, err still there

I also **tried config's browser optio**n. it false too

first, I thought it just Puppeteer problem(because I used that first)

so I tried alternative things and this is result all same

**my node version 16.19.0** (I have coworkers, I can't change the version)

why I meet this same problems?

Comment: Are you trying to run Webdriver or Playwright _in a React app_?! See e.g. https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/differences-between-nodejs-and-the-browser/

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank! but I think puppeteer is for node.js Program.. but that have same issue

Comment: I have one possible reason. I worked only client. Because the project is developing separately(front and back)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason.

I don't use a node server.
if I want use puppeteer or some another livery for dynamic scraping  , I need to use node server